# Не вызывается деструктор

Tags: c++, функции, классы, c++17, деструктор

Весь код:

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
class MyClass
{
public:
    int data;
    MyClass(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        cout << "Вызвался конструктор " << this << '\n';
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        cout << "Вызвался деструктор " << this << '\n';
    }
};
void Foo(MyClass value)
{
    cout << "Вызвалась функция Foo " << '\n';
}
MyClass Foo2()
{
    cout << "Вызвалась функция Foo2 " << '\n';
    MyClass temp(2);
 
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
 
    //MyClass a(1);
    //Foo(a);
    Foo2();
 
    return 0;
}
```

В моменте в

```
return temp;
```

не вызывается второй деструктор как должно быть по словам автора одного программиста. Почему не вызывается второй деструктор?

Comment: А почему он должен вызываться? Вы никуда ничего не возвращаете, да  если бы и возвращали — [NRVO](https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/666330/) сработала бы. Тут все верно.

Comment: У автора видео о конструкторах копирования вызывается 2 деструктора. Код идентичен.
https://youtu.be/3x9nd6Tm7Pc?t=640

Comment: компилятор **может** с оптимизировать. А в стандарте C++17 **обязан**. Это видео было записано в 2017 году, и он не показывает свои настройки оптимизации и в каком стандарте он всё показывает.

Comment: чтобы явно вызывался второй конструктор можно попробовать передавать `volatile` объект : `MyClass(MyClass volatile const & m) { .. } .. MyClass volatile Foo3(){ cout << "Вызвалась функция Foo3 " << '\n'; MyClass volatile temp(3); return temp; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело оптимизатора — применить NVRO или нет.

Компилирую ваш код в VC++ 2019 с ключиками

```
/std:c++latest /O2 /Ot /Oi /Ox /Oy /Ob2
```

ну, т.е. полная оптимизация. На выходе:

```
Вызвалась функция Foo2 
Вызвался конструктор 0000007982EFF920
Вызвался деструктор 0000007982EFF920
```

Теперь компилирую с

```
/std:c++latest /Od
```

и получаю

```
Вызвалась функция Foo2 
Вызвался конструктор 000000E0FD0FF904
Вызвался деструктор 000000E0FD0FF904
Вызвался деструктор 000000E0FD0FF940
```

Думаю, дальше пояснять ничего не надо?

Кстати, если возвращать просто

```
MyClass Foo2()
{
    cout << "Вызвалась функция Foo2 " << '\n';
    return 2;
}
```

то конструктор-деструктор будут и при оптимизации.